# Reduce the amount of space taken by media player in split view

Tags: media-player, multi-window

I am using the Split View functionality of my Android tablet to read e-books while also listening to their audio-book versions. For this purpose, I need to have most of my screen given to the e-pub reader and only a narrow bar assigned to the media player. I have already tried the VLC media player and some other ones but they take up about one-fourth of the valuable space.

Any ideas on how I might reduce the amount of space taken by the audio player? Or are there any players you know with the desired functionality in Split View mode?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. For app recommendations, perhaps you might also be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: What about the easiest solution: let the media player run in background. Player controls should be accessible in the notification bar.